# Seeking the Best Value Object Storage Solution？

Tags: cloud, blogs, self-hosting, cloud-storage

I'm in the process of building a self-hosted image-hosting service for my blog, and I need your help in finding the right solution. Here are my requirements:

**Ample Storage Space:** I need a provider that offers large amounts of storage space to accommodate my blog's image-hosting needs.

**Fast Image Access:** It's crucial for my blog's performance that images can be accessed quickly. I want to ensure that the image loading time is minimal, providing a seamless user experience.

**Easy-to-Use API:** An intuitive and user-friendly API is essential to integrate the image hosting service smoothly with my blog. I'm looking for a provider that offers an API that's straightforward to implement.

**Cost Considerations:** I've explored popular cloud providers like AWS S3 and Azure Blob, but their pricing at $0.023 per GB/month is a bit expensive for my budget. I've also researched alternatives such as Cloudflare R2, BackBlaze B2, Wasabi, IDrive, and Hetzner Storage Box. Nevertheless, I am uncertain about the quality and usability of their respective APIs.

**Global Distribution:** Since the main users of my blog are in North America and Asia, it's important to have servers distributed globally. I want to ensure that the image latency is under 1 second, regardless of the user's location.

I would greatly appreciate any recommendations based on my requirements. If you have experience with any specific providers or suggestions, please share your insights. Your expertise will be invaluable in helping me make an informed decision.

Thanks in advance for your help!

You can check my blog: [WitnessJ's Cornucopia](https://witnessj.com/)

Looking forward to your responses :)

my expectations were to discover a cost-effective storage solution that offers a substantial storage capacity, fast global access, and an easy-to-use API. I aimed to strike a balance between affordability and performance while catering to the needs of my blog's users located primarily in North America and Asia.

Comment: Additionally, I am also considering using a CDN for my image hosting service. If you have any insights or information regarding reliable and cost-effective CDN providers, please feel free to share your recommendations. I'm particularly interested in finding a CDN solution that offers a balance between quality performance and affordability. Any suggestions or experiences you can share would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!